# How to copy Buffer bytes block in Poco C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, poco-libraries

Hi i am trying to write a TCP connection in poco. the client sends a packet with this fields :

`packetSize : int
 date : int
 ID : int`

so the first 4 bytes contains the packet size. in the receive side i have this code :

```
int packetSize = 0;
char *bufferHeader = new char[4];

// receive 4 bytes that contains packetsize here
socket().receiveBytes(bufferHeader, sizeof(bufferHeader), MSG_WAITALL);

Poco::MemoryInputStream *inStreamHeader = new Poco::MemoryInputStream(bufferHeader, sizeof(bufferHeader));
Poco::BinaryReader *BinaryReaderHeader = new Poco::BinaryReader(*inStreamHeader);

(*BinaryReaderHeader) >> packetSize; // now we have the full packet size
```

Now I am trying to store all remaining incoming bytes into one array for future binary reading :

```
int ID = 0;
int date = 0;
int availableBytes = 0;
int readedBytes = 0;
char *body = new char[packetSize - 4];

do
{
    char *bytes = new char[packetSize - 4];

    availableBytes = socket().receiveBytes(bytes, sizeof(bytes), MSG_WAITALL);

    if (availableBytes == 0)
        break;

    memcpy(body + readedBytes, bytes, availableBytes);

    readedBytes += availableBytes;

} while (availableBytes > 0);

Poco::MemoryInputStream *inStream = new Poco::MemoryInputStream(body, sizeof(body));
Poco::BinaryReader *BinaryReader = new Poco::BinaryReader(*inStream);

(*BinaryReader) >> date;
(*BinaryReader) >> ID;

cout << "date :" << date << endl;
cout << "ID :" << ID << endl;
```

the problem is the byte block of body is not storing the remaining bytes , it has always only the first 4 bytes (date). so in the out put the date is correct but the ID is not as expected. I tried to Stream it without Block copy and manually receive the each field without loop, it was just fine and had expected data. but when i try to store the incoming bytes into one array and then pass that array to a memorystream to read it, i have only the first block correct and expected!!

I really need to store all incoming bytes into one array and then read whole that array, how should i change my code?

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two errors in your code. Or, more precisely, an error you do twice.
You confuse `sizeof` of `char[]` with `sizeof` of `char *`; the first is the number of characters in the array, the second is the size of the pointer: typically 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the memory model.

So, when you write

```
availableBytes = socket().receiveBytes(bytes, sizeof(bytes), MSG_WAITALL);
```

you are asking for 4 (I suppose) bytes. This is not serious as you continue to ask other bytes until the message is finished.

The real problem is the following instruction

```
Poco::MemoryInputStream *inStream = new Poco::MemoryInputStream(body, sizeof(body));
```

where you transfer only `sizeof(char *)` bytes in `inStream`

You should substitute `sizeof(body)` and `sizeof(bytes)` with `packetSize - 4`.

P.s.: sorry for my bad english

**Edit**: I've seen another error. In this instruction

```
 char *bytes = new char[packetSize - 4];
```

you allocate `packetSize - 4` chars. This memory in never deleted and in allocated in the `do ... while()` cycle.

You can allocate `bytes` outside of the cycle (togheter with `body`).

**Edit 2016.03.17**

Proposed solution (caution: non tested)

```
size_t  toRead  = packetSize - 4U;
size_t  totRead = 0U;
size_t  nowRead;

char * body = new char[toRead];

do 
{
  nowRead += socket().receiveBytes(body+totRead, toRead-totRead,
                MSG_WAITALL);

  if ( 0 == nowRead )
     throw std::runtime_error("shutdown from receiveBytes()");

  totRead += nowRead;

} while ( totRead < toRead );

Poco::MemoryInputStream *inStream = new Poco::MemoryInputStream(body, 
                                           toRead);

delete[] body;

body = NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for ur response. yes i was confusing about that , after all when I am changing char * to char [ ] I am getting full packet there. but actually when I am trying to consider packetSize for my buffer I cant resize the Char [ ] in fact c++ doesnt accept it for size of array it needs the constant value, but it accepts it as : `char * buffer = new char[packetSize]` and when I consider char * , I am getting the only 4 bytes each time and not the full packet. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @AmirHasanHesam: I think you should avoid this use of `sizeof()`; you have the number of expected bytes: use it. And you can use only one buffer. I'll edit my answer to show a possible solution.